# What figure of speech or literary device is the following?

Tags: figures-of-speech, literary-device

What figure of speech or literary device is it when multiple interpretations are possible of a particular verse or words?

Comment: What research have you done so far? Have you looked, for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity#Linguistic_forms

Comment: There's a book about this: *[Seven Types of Ambiguity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Types_of_Ambiguity)* by William Empson.

Comment: This is often used as part of a pun. Can you give examples of the particular form that you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for ***polysemy***:

> : the coexistence of many possible meanings for a word or phrase.
>
> ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/polysemy#:%7E:text=The%20coexistence%20of%20many%20possible%20meanings%20for%20a%20word%20or%20phrase.))

> a condition in which a single word, phrase, or concept has more than one meaning or connotation.
>
> ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/polysemous))

> Polysemy is defined as having several meanings, or being open to several interpretations.
>
> ([yourdictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/polysemy))